# How do I add linebreaks to a property in an ASP.NET control declaration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a sql data source and I have a really long string of SQL. I want to put linebreaks in my sql but Visual Studio doesn't seem to like the linebreaks. How would I put in line breaks?

Example

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"         
        ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
        SelectCommand="select aci.ACIOI, aci.AccountNum, (select count(r.OI) from Report r where aci.ACIOI = r.ACIOI) as ReportCount, ci.Name, aci.BusinessName, ci.[Address] As StreetAddress, ci.Town, ci.Zip, ci.Phone  from AdditionalCustomerInformation aci  left join CustomerInformation ci on ci.ACI_OI = aci.ACIOI where (select count(r.OI) from Report r where aci.ACIOI = r.ACIOI) >= 1" 
        >        
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This compiles just fine for me:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="select aci.ACIOI, 
aci.AccountNum, (select count(r.OI) from Report r where aci.ACIOI = r.ACIOI) as ReportCount,
ci.Name, aci.BusinessName, 
ci.[Address] As StreetAddress, ci.Town, 
ci.Zip, ci.Phone 
from AdditionalCustomerInformation aci left join CustomerInformation ci on ci.ACI_OI = aci.ACIOI 
where (select count(r.OI) from Report r where aci.ACIOI = r.ACIOI) >=1"> </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

... which is logical. The compiler should not care if your markup is broken up into separate lines as long as the entire SQL statement is enclosed in quotes of the `SelectCommand` property.

**The problem it appears is because of the `>` symbol in your SQL statement.** There are two ways to escape that symbol. You could simply use the `&gt;` HTML entity instead, as follows:

```
SelectCommand = "SELECT.... &gt;= 1"
```

Comment: Ahh, Thanks for the heads up. I seem to recall reading that it works sometime back.

Comment: FYI - The @ in your last example is still there.

Answer (score 1):

HTML escaping is required. Replace your > with &gt;

Likewise, < becomes &lt;