# Recursive CTE not working with SqlDataSource in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a `SqlDataSource` in my ASP.NET application. The query is working fine in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.

But in the ASP.NET application, it returns no values.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="ChartOfAccountsFillerDS" runat="server"
      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>" 
      SelectCommand = "with cte as(select ChartOfAccountsID, Parent_ChartOfAccountsID, GL_Code, AccountName, 1 as [Level],
                            right('000' + cast(row_number()over(partition by Parent_ChartOfAccountsID order by GL_Code) as varchar(max)), 3) as [Path]
                            from ChartOfAccounts where Parent_ChartOfAccountsID is null
                            union all select t.ChartOfAccountsID, t.Parent_ChartOfAccountsID, t.GL_Code, t.AccountName, [Level] + 1,
                            [Path] + '.' + right('000' + cast(row_number()over(partition by t.Parent_ChartOfAccountsID order by t.GL_Code) as varchar(max)), 3)
                            from cte join ChartOfAccounts t on t.Parent_ChartOfAccountsID = cte.ChartOfAccountsID)
                            select ChartOfAccountsID as AccountID, Parent_ChartOfAccountsID as ParentID, GL_Code, (REPLICATE(CHAR(160), ([Level] -1)*5) +  AccountName) AccountName, [Level], [Path] from cte  order by [Path]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason for `SqlDataSource` does not support CTE expressions IMHO. Are you really sure your connection string, the database you connect and schema are right?

Comment: Yes its working well with simple select query. I tried SqlDataReader in C#. Its not working there either. returning false on Read() function.

Comment: It seems you have something wrong with parenthesis. The first one "with cte as **(** select" is closed by "from cte join ChartOfAccounts t on t.Parent_ChartOfAccountsID = cte.ChartOfAccountsID **)**". Is this correct?

Comment: @Andrei It's recursive CTE.

Comment: I suspected that [this might be](http://stackoverflow.com/a/735279/578411) a reason but I don't see that in your query. I can only suggest to take out stuff until it runs and then add things back until it breaks.  Sorry ... :(

Comment: I spent 3 days to make a query like this to order my data hierarchically :(

Comment: Sure, I'm not disputing that effort, I am trying to provide you a way to eliminate possible causes. Just try it without the union all construct in the cte and without the fields that do the `replicate`, `right` functions stuff, so just plain fields. If that works, add the union all construct back in without the fields that use functions. If that works add back the fields with the functions. Somewhere in that process your stuff will break. It will be interesting to know when that is.

Comment: I got it working. It was a stupid Mistake I did. 
In my Query, I am finding Parents by checking NULLs.  "where Parent_ChartOfAccountsID is null". But in my local database, Instead of NULL, the ParentID was its own ID. :)